# Inheriting TargetDB between different packages in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a multi-layer SSIS project. Basic structure is as follows:

```
|-- Package level 0 (MASTER package that contains references to other packages)

    |-- Package level 1 (contains references to another package)
        |-- Package level 1.1 (execute sql task nodes and dataviewers package 1.1 specific)

    |-- Package level 1 (contains references to another package)
        |-- Package level 1.2 (execute sql task nodes and dataviewers package 1.2 specific)

    ...
```

Right now to make my project work I need to have the connection manager OLE DB (TargetDB) defined within every package. I dislike this approach, because as the number of packages grows - the number of adjustments needed grows as well.

I want to define the TargetDB only once, on the MASTER (0 level). Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't able to create the environment variable due to the VS version (2010) I decided to:

1. Add foreach loop which finds every .dtsx file within folder.
2. For every dtsx file the c# script finds and replaces target db.

   ```
       string fileText;
       try
       {
           fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Dts.Variables["User::TargetDB_CurrentFile"].Value.ToString());
           fileText = fileText.Replace("PUT DB NAME HERE", Dts.Variables["User::TargetDB_Name"].Value.ToString());
           System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Dts.Variables["User::TargetDB_CurrentFile"].Value.ToString(), fileText);

           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
           throw ex;
       }
       finally
       {
           fileText = null;
       }

       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   ```

Thanks that approach I can set up my all .dtsx packages at once. I found it very convenient. The same logic might be applied for setting up any repeating variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - create and map an [environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213230.aspx). When you deploy it will need mapping for each package BUT will only need to be maintained once in the environment.

You don't mention which version you are running - this works for SQL2012 onwards.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Visual Studio 2010, is there any option to do that within this version?